# Why circular 8 looks better than square 8

Tags: typography, shapes, symbols

Here is a drawing of the two:

[image]

The circular 8 is much more common than the square "shape" that kind of could be considered an 8 on the right.

I would like to know why.

In both shapes there are clearly two "divisions", and they both have the same "orientation". So it seems they should be both equally 8. They also don't really conflict with any other shape I don't think, well maybe `0` a little bit.

Comment: I prefer a hexagonal 8 myself `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you mean. Who says one is better than the other and in what context? The ['circular' 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8#Glyph) has a [long history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) tracing back to the 3rd-4th-5th century in modern day India and Iraq, while the 'square' version is a more recent development (20th century) due to limitations in early electronic devices, where displays where just able to construct simple shapes using a [7-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display).

[image]

[image]